# GitLab user validation by organization?

Tags: gitlab

Since 17 May 2021 Gitlab enforced user validation via credit card details, but is there a way for a company or organization to validate their users or validate their actions on their repositories?

Answer (score 5):

After a detailed research, I found that user validation is only required if shared runners are enabled. If organization use their own runner then disable runners and for new users card validation will not be required.

Thats how for now I resolved my problem

Comment: mujiksan ukam rahmat